Data type implementation of 1.58 bits
In Large Language Models, using 1-bit binary weights (BitNet: Scaling 1-bit Transformers for Large Language Models - Wang et al, 2023) instead of 32-bit floating point weights has numerous advantages. Some of the recent research (The Era of 1-bit LLMs:
All Large Language Models are in 1.58 Bits - Ma et al, 2024) on LLMs talks about using 1.58 bits weights. By this they mean using {-1, 0, +1} instead of {-1, +1} as the quantized value of the weights, as was the convention in previous work on binarization and 1-bit weights.
I fail to understand the datatype of 1.58-bit weights. Are they defining a new type of binary/boolean value? Are they using 2-bit integers? How exactly is it implemented?

Just rumor at this point, but I've heard rumblings that 1-trit models are not everything the original papers suggest. Perhaps others can provide references that give a better understanding of what we know of them right now.

Here's a question from the artificial intelligence site on this topic.

That's not very relevant  to this question tbh. One of the answers to that question is from me.

I'm NOT saying it is a duplicate!  Just that it is, broadly, on the topic of 1.58-bit weights.

Why are you asking this question on this site instead of the AI site?  Isn't this more on topic for that site?

@JosiahYoder, yes but 1) implementation of datatypes, bit packing, etc., are topics closer to CS than to AI and 2) on the AI site, I saw recent questions and answers doubting the possibility (not accuracy) of ternary models, even though such models have been proposed and implemented for many years now.

They are using trinary values which have an information density of $\log_2 3 = 1.584963...$ bits per trinary digit.
The effective implementation for computation in traditional compute devices is going to be 2 bits in a signed magnitude style. They can be stored using a variety of tricks, one of which would be using 1 byte to store 5 trinary digits.
In more specialized ASICs this can be implemented using different voltage levels

Hi. This is actually not the case. I wrote to one of the authors who clarified that they are using bit-packing. https://compilade.net/blog/ternary-packing https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp/pull/8151
This effectively means that 8 bits can be used to hold 5 trits.

I did specify for computation, I fully expect the weights to be compressed and uncompressed into the 2 bit per weight representation at some point.

Looks like the code unpacks each ternary value to 8 bits because that is the smallest element size supported by most SIMD instruction sets.

@jpa Indeed. To perform arithmetic while the bits are still packed will involve coming up with new operations and logic. That is doable when you pack a trit in 2-bits (4 trits per byte). But simply unpacking is the easiest and most robust at this stage. I'm sure they'll optimize later on. When it is 5 trits per byte, these operations need to get a little creative. If you look in the Ma et al paper towards the end, they do suggest the development of hardware support for their models.

For 2-bit integers, signed magnitude and two's complement are the same for { -1, 0, 1 }.
